# How to make an API request in broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-volley

*Request from server to android application as a notification. Read response by application.*

Comment: From where are you getting broadcast? Anyway you can check out this link and add your api call inside that . https://android.jlelse.eu/local-broadcast-less-overhead-and-secure-in-android-cfa343bb05be

Comment: i am getting broadcast from server. @VrushiPatel

Comment: How exactly are you doing that can please explain?

Comment: @VrushiPatel  Server send me the data (xml or JSON data) to the application. application should receive as notification that notification read by application. Did you get that?

Comment: hey @RohitB. can you explain in detail what you want to achieve after you got the notification?

Comment: Hi @AvinashAjayPandey after i get notification i want to display data in activity.